# Accessing one-to-many association from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a one-to-many association between 2 resources: Discovery and Matter

```
class Discovery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matter
end

class Matter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discoveries
end
```

My routes file has this:

```
resources :matters do
  resources :discoveries
end
```

My migration files look like:

```
class CreateDiscoveries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :discoveries do |t|
      t.string :aws_url
      t.string :upload_file_path
      t.attachment :upload
      t.integer :matter_id
      t.string :direct_upload_url
      t.boolean :processed

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddMatterIdToDiscoveries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :discoveries, :matter_id
    add_index :discoveries, :processed
  end
end
```

discoveries_controller.rb

```
def create
  @matter = Matter.find(params[:matter_id])
  if(params[:url])
    @discovery = Discovery.new
    render "new" and return
  end

  if(params[:discovery][:upload_file_path])
    @discovery = Discovery.new(discovery_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @discovery.save
        @discovery.matter = current_user.matters.find(params[:matter_id])
        format.html { render action: :show, notice: 'Discovery was successfully created.' } # matter_url(@discovery.matter_id)
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @discovery }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @discovery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      # redirect_to new_document and return
    end
  else
    @discovery = Discovery.new
    render action: 'new', notice: "No file"
  end
end
```

When I create a new discovery in the matters model `matters/3/discoveries/new` the discovery gets created, but in the console, I thought I should be able to access `Discovery.last.matter`, but instead I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'matter' for #<Discovery:0x0000000495dc98>`

How would I go about showing the matter that the discovery belongs to? Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your migration for Discovery

Comment: added the migrations for Discovery

Comment: That is not a many-to-many association.

Comment: Matter.find(Discovery.last.matter_id) ?

Comment: You are right, it totally is a one-to-many

Comment: Discovery.last.matter_id is nil. Why would the matter_id not be getting populated? Sorry, just getting started with rails.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the `create` method inside your `DiscoveriesController`. Care to paste that in too?

Comment: controller added too

Comment: I believe a side effect is that after submit is pressed, the new discovery is rendered at the url: `/matters/3/discoveries` and I can see that the `:matter_id = 3`, but when navigating to `/matters/3/discoveries/135', `:matter_id = nil`

Comment: Yep. `@discovery.matter = current_user.matters.find(params[:matter_id])` needed to go outside of the `if @discovery.save` for the matter to be associated.. Thanks for going down that journey with me guys!

Answer (score 1):

Call `reload!` in the console after changing your models (schema changes, running migrations, adding methods).

Comment: Sometimes this is not enough. At times you have to re-instantiate the objects, and other times it's just easier to exit the console and restart a new session.